# Keeping H2 database running on Amazon EC2

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, h2

I currently have an webapp on Amazon's EC2. The app uses the H2 database to store tables ( I used scp to import my H2 directory from local machine to EC2). The app works when I connect to the instance and startup the H2, but once I close the local Terminal, H2 stops and the app also stops working. Is there a way to keep H2 running even after I close the Terminal locally?

Answer (score 0):

Most database systems are services and run as a process in the background rather than within a given user session.

It does appear that it has some kind of server mode: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server

It doesn't provide much information about how to set up init scripts for it however.

A quick Google searched turned up this example:
https://gist.github.com/ohneda/1585636

Comment: I found a different way to do this, by using the sub-terminal screen, i can have H2 running in it without it closing after exiting the terminal. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: That is not really a great way to run a service. It wont get launched again when your system restarts.